# Is it possible to select multiple tables to view as one big table in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

so I'm using the DB2 scripting from IBM i / System i (and old version where Collection is used instead of Schema)

and I noticed that its becoming tedious to having to keep typing

"select * from mycollectionName.whatever" for each table.

is there anyway I can select from multiple tables and have it display all the information in one big table?

example:

```
CREATE TABLE UMALIK8.ADULTS (
ADULT_NUM VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UMALIK8.ADULTS_PK PRIMARY KEY,
ADULT_L_NAME CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ADULT_F_NAME CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
RELATIONSHIP CHAR (30) NOT NULL,
STREET VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
APT_NUM VARCHAR (10),
CITY CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
POSTAL_CODE VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
HOMEPHONE VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
WORKPHONE VARCHAR (20));

CREATE TABLE UMALIK8.EMPLOYEE (
EMP_NUM VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
EMP_L_NAME CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
EMP_F_NAME CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PAYRATE DECIMAL (10, 2) NOT NULL,
POSNCODE VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
HIREDATE DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UMALIK8.EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMP_NUM),
CONSTRAINT UMALIK8.EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (POSNCODE)
REFERENCES UMALIK8.POSITION(POSNCODE));
```

I have these two tables, and I've created my Insert statement for them.

Now I want to select them and view them across a big table, instead of having to switch tabs (in Run Script from System i Navigator).

Is this possible? Is it better to make individual select statement for each table i create?

Would I do something along the lines of this?

```
Select * From umalik8.Adults, umalik8.Employee
    WHERE umalik8.Adults = umalik8.Employee
```

***EDIT***

Okay, so I kinda got lucky and tried this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM UMALIK8.SYSTABLES;     


SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
    FROM UMALIK8.syscolumns;
```

AND it almost worked...it shows me all the tables and all the columns in each tab, EXCEPT what was inserted (the record).

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: It gives me an error, "WHERE umalik8.Adults" (and I'm assuming its the same case with Employee because it stops at adults), error number sql0206, column or global variable ADULTS not found. wasn't found as a column of any table. I read the error code online but just confused me more lol.

Because if i did Select * From umalik8.adults; the table will be displayed. However if I do it like this, nothing happens :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am not sure this is possible, but [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_joindatafromtables.htm) tutorial about `joins` could be a good read.

Or [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafyjoin.htm) for your iSeries / IBM i edition of DB2.

Comment: had no idea about Joins, this looks like what I'm trying to do, i'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: Alright so I've come to the conclusion with some trial and errors, looks like this is the best way to do it, using the Join methods (inner and outer), but of course, logically, we should join tables with other tables that make sense LOL....joining registered adults with employees for a daycare was odd....

thanks FranklySpeaking!

Comment: I would think that what you have is an ancillary relationship here.  Presumably all employees are considered adults, so an employees address could be found in the adults table, where the adult_num = emp_num.  You might have other adult records for parents or guardians of the children in the daycare.